# Maven SAR packaging: generating several sar files

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, sar

I'm new to maven and I wonder if I can get Maven to package up more than one SAR in a single build using the jboss-packaging-maven-plugin.

I have different jboss-service.xml files in different folders, but I don't know how to configure the plugin to generate those .sar files.

Jboss-service.xml files are under src/main/resources/META-INF-:

> src/
>
> ```
>   |__main/
>          |__resources/
>                       |
>                       |_META-INF-TEST/jboss-service.xml
>                       |
>                       |_META-INF-PROD/jboss-service.xml
>                       |
>                       |_META-INF-LOCAL/jboss-service.xml
> ```

The desired result should be:

> -> myproject-TEST.sar
>
> -> myproject-PROD.sar
>
> -> myproject-LOCAL.sar

Thanks in advance!